# Collect variables with the same name pattern in VIM

Tags: vim

From the following

```
# industrials
# * airlines: AAL
aal_score = run("AAL")

# information technology
# * MSFT
# * AAPL
msft_score = run("MSFT")
aapl_score = run("AAPL")

# materials
# * Agnico Eagle Mines AEM
aem_score = run("AEM")

# telecommunication services
# * ATT
att_score = run("ATT")

# utilities
# * AEP
aep_score = run("AEP")
```

I would like to collect the variable names and print their values, like

```
print "AAL score {%2.2f}".format(aal_score)
print "MSFT score {%2.2f}".format(msft_score)
print "AAPL score {%2.2f}".format(aapl_score)
...
```

How to do that efficiently in Vim?

Comment: This looks like python. Why not use e.g. a dict with the stock symbols as keys? Then there would be less boilerplate to try and automate with vim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a pipelined command which does what you want and you will find the result in a file called `Output`:

```
:g/^\s*\(\w*_score\)\s*=\s*run("\(\w*\)").*$/ s//&\rprint "\2 score {2.2f}".format(\1)/ | :. w! >> Output | normal! dd
```

---

- Explanation:

---

The command above is actually divided into 3 commands:

1. **`:g/^\s*\(\w*_score\)\s*=\s*run("\(\w*\)").*$/ s//&\rprint "\2 score {2.2f}".format(\1)/`**

the first thing is the global search which searches for lines with the pattern `^\s*\(\w*_score\)\s*=\s*run("\(\w*\)").*$` (i.e these lines)

> aal_score = run("AAL")
>
> msft_score = run("MSFT")
>
> aapl_score = run("AAPL")
>
> aem_score = run("AEM")
>
> att_score = run("ATT")
>
> aep_score = run("AEP")

--[-----\1------]---------[  \2  ]

on every line we catch the required text by surrounding it into `\(...\)`  *(backreferencing & grouping)* then we use the substitution:

```
s//&\rprint "\2 score {2.2f}".format(\1)/
```

which generates each time (ex:)

> aep_score = run("AEP")
>
> print "AEP score {2.2f}".format(aep_score)

2. **`:. w! >> Output`**

for the second command we will write the print line at the end of the file Output

3. **`normal! dd`** or **`:.d`**

delete the print line from the current file

Comment: would you mind break down the command and explain what the components do? I'm new to Vim so I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @Menix Thank you so much :)